# getting connection timeout error while connecting to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, docker

springboot Application is running in localhost docker and trying to connect to database, however getting the below error in logs

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:75) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
```

below is logs from postgresql data/logs folder

```
2023-02-28 07:15:59.986 IST [63724] FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-02-28 08:47:15.571 IST [317] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2023-02-28 08:47:15.716 IST [317] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 352) exited with exit code 1
2023-02-28 08:47:15.741 IST [347] LOG:  shutting down
2023-02-28 08:47:15.810 IST [317] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

This is how I'm connecting to the DB in code:

```
DATASOURCE_CONNECTION_STRING=jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5433/test
DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password
```

Please note: direct connection to pgAdmin panel also gives the below error.
[image]

can anyone please help

---

Update, after installing new version of postgreSQL, it worked. however now I have two instances, postgreSQL 14 is still having same issue and postgreSQL15 is working fine.
[image]

Comment: see 
https://zpz.github.io/blog/connect-to-localhost-from-container/

Comment: "Connection timed out" is a network problem. If you shut down your database, that's another, unrelated problem. Research in that direction.

Comment: Lacks details, `host.docker.internal` seems to be resolving to `localhost`, (1) the default `postgresql` port is `5432`, is the host port `5433` mapped to the containers port `5432` or (2) is the `postgresql` instance configured with non-default port `5433` and running on the `host` network or (3) ...?

Comment: Just an update after long time, 
I could not resolve that issue, so as a last resort to continue with my work, I just downloaded new version of postgreSQL15 and set it up. which is now working. issue is still coming with postgreSQL 14